# Javascript code number likes by typescript / angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I have some javascript code which I'm trying to add to my `component.ts` in my angular project.

Here is the code:

```
ngOninit() {
  let areaNum = document.getElementsByClassName("some-area").length;

  // The issue is in the code below:
  for (let area of document.getElementsByClassName("some-area")) {
    area.style.height = 100 / areaNum + "%";
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
```

How can I fix this so it work in Angular?

Comment: Why don't you try to write that code inside AfterViewInit?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it looks like you're trying to dynamically assign element heights based on how many there are. I would suggest using flex-layout or grids for this. heres a link to angular's flex layout module: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout. the bottom of their readme includes links to examples and wikis

Comment: passing the elements (as variables) to that component as inputs lets you do ngFor things in that components html. Adding a flex layout surround it will set the bounds for the entire lists container, and then for how much of the container's height each element gets

Comment: I agree with @smcrowley. There is no need to use javascript to update the height in this case. pixelKus2022 you should avoid this at all cost and use [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: Using CSS is indeed a much better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live `HTMLCollection`. [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

You can make it into an array using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("some-area"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use CSS Only, no need for javascript

Why are you updating html from angular functions via javascript. Based on your code you should actually style the div (`some-area`'s parent element) to be `display:flex` and the children `some-area` to have `flex:1`.

**Once the style is in place, you can add 1 or 1000 elements and it will always display it right.**

The angular / javascript should only be responsible for adding and removing the elements. You must try to avoid such type of style manipulation from javascript at all times.

### Requirement

You want to equally space the `some-area` element inside their container so that their heights are `100% / number of elements`.

This can be simply achieved by using CSS Flex-box no need to get javascript involved.

### Better Solution

```css
.container {
  /* Boilerplate Style */
  height:100vh;
  gap:10px;

  /* Important Style */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-area {
  /* Boilerplate Style */
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  
  /* Important Style */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-area">some content</div>
  <div class="some-area">some content</div>
  <div class="some-area">some content</div>
  <div class="some-area">some content</div>
</div>
```